# while loop division go below decided number

Tags: php, while-loop, division

This code will divide the score until it reaches the number 5.

The $rows[score] is equal to 6600 in the database.

```
<?php
    $i = $rows[score]; //score is 6600 in the database
    while ($i >= 5) {
        echo $i = $i /2; 
        echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

This is what my browser outputs:

3300

1650

825

412.5

206.25

103.125

51.5625

25.78125

12.890625

6.4453125

3.22265625

**I don't understand why the browser output the last 3.22 - how do I stop the loop from echo out the last one that is less than 5??**

Answer (score 2):

Nothing wrong here the last value you get is from `6.4453125 / 2 = 3.22265625` since `6.4453125` still greater than `5`

Comment: how do I stop the loop from echo out the 3.2 value?

Comment: You can set your `$i` at least greater than `6.4453125`, for example `while ($i >= 6.5)`

Answer (score 0):

because 6 is higher than 5? so it does one more loop making $i 3.2 where the loop stops

Comment: how do I stop the loop from echo out the 3.2 value?

Answer (score 0):

If `($i<5)` it wont go into the loop but there is no way to know until you check. `$i = 6.4453125` the last time it checks, so it goes into the loop and it divides it by 2, which makes it less than 5 so it doesn't go into the loop again and stops.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to answer my own question so 3,22 will not be viewed on the page.

```
<?php
$i = $rows[score]; //score is 6600 in the database
while ($i >= 5) {
    $i = $i /2; 

    if($i >= 5) {
    echo $i;
    echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: kinda pointless to test $i twice for the same thing. why not just change your condition to `while($i >= 6.5)`? That'll output the 6.4, then terminate

Answer (score 0):

Since you're dividing by two immediately before displaying the result, you want to stop your loop when $i >= (5*2) i.e. $i >= 10, not 5.

```
<?php
$i = $rows[score]; //score is 6600 in the database
while ($i >= 10) {
    echo $i = $i /2; 
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
```

This gives:

```
3300
1650
825
412.5
206.25
103.125
51.5625
25.78125
12.890625
6.4453125
```